# Bootstrap 2 - correct way to centre a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am using Bootstrap with the Yii framework - and am trying to centre my login box in the middle of the page, but not having any joy.

My code looks like as follows:

How should I amend this to have the div display bang on in the centre?

A jsfiddle -:
http://jsfiddle.net/7946rak9/1/

```
        <div class="row">
        <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id' => get_class($model),
            'enableAjaxValidation'      => true,
            'clientOptions' => array(
                'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                'validateOnChange' => false,
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'form-vertical'),
            'action'                    => array('/frontend/user/login')
        )); ?>

        <div class="span2">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username', array('class' => '')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model, 'username', array('class'=>'errorMessage')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password', array('class' => '')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model, 'password', array('class'=>'errorMessage')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset2 span10">
            <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe', array('class' => 'pull-left')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'rememberMe', array('style' => 'padding-left: 20px;')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model, 'rememberMe', array('class'=>'errorMessage')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset2 span3">
            <?php echo Html::submitButton('Login', array('class' => 'btn')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

Comment: What could help is that you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ exemple with your HTML code only so we can help by showing you the correct css way to do this.

Comment: i will do so now good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

If you want to use Bootstrap 2's included markup, use the following to offset your div to the middle of the row.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span4 offset3">...</div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

**Alternative**

Or you could wrap all your divs with another div and then use the following markup.

```
<div class="wrapper">
....all you content divs here
</div>


.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7946rak9/2/

Comment: Brilliant - the span4 offset3 line made it click in my head thanks!

Answer (score 2):

have you tried adding another class "text-center" to the row div?

Comment: that doesn't work for me.. (although looking at the css that class should work..) i'll keep trying

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

`margin: 0 auto;`

On the div you would like to center

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `text-align: center;` on the div you want to centre

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>

#mydiv {
text-align: center;
}
```

Should do the trick. **[Simple Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5fjs047c/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try defining classes `span2` and `span 10` with `text-align: center;` in your CSS if you're using a pre 2.3.0 version of Bootstrap - the `.text-center` method, suggested by @Wu4D wasn't added until v2.3.